# Writing a custom IRB

Tags: c, ruby, irb, systems-programming, mruby

I'm playing around with all sorts of small hardware. In an attempt to learn it. I would like to run mruby. I've compiled for my hardware. And have the framework as well as the include MIRB and MRUBY bins.

But I would potentially like the code my own IRB. I am a programmer by trade, but have never dealt in anything this low level since college.

Where do i begin in the process, my google-foo is not cutting it.

Comment: take a look at pry which is an open source REPL for ruby: https://github.com/pry/pry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you can execute ruby code on the platform you are running on, it's just a matter of gluing up together [eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) and [readline](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html). For something more advanced, I advice you to take a look at the [ruby source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby), you will find the complete irb sources in `bin/irb.rb`, `lib/irb.rb` and the `lib/irb` direcotry. Have fun!